# ZFC-Infinity+PA: Does it prove Con(PA)?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms, meta-math

We define the theory ZFC-Infinity+PA as follows. We start with the axioms of ZFC-Infinity. Next we assert that there is a model of arithmetic $(\mathbb N, 0, S, +, \times)$. Next, for every axiom of (first-order) PA, we assert that $(\mathbb N, 0, S, +, \times)$ obeys it. Each axiom of PA corresponds to a separate axiom of ZFC-Infinity+PA.

Note in particular that the theory does *not* know that $(\mathbb N, 0, S, +, \times)$ is a model of PA, since proving that would require invoking infinitely many axioms.

We *do* know that $\mathbb N$ is dedekind-infinite though, since the axioms of PA imply $S$ is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N - \{0\}$.

So, can this theory prove that PA is consistient?

Comment: What do you mean by "we assert that there is a model of arithmetic"? It looks like you just want to say that there is a named structure (a set, a constant in the set, an unary function and two binary functions), and only then you add axioms which make it a model of arithmetic

Comment: Anyway, is it obvious your theory does not prove infinity?

Comment: I don't understand. Is $\mathbb N $ a set? If so, then your theory proves infinity. Maybe you want to clarify this point.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo $\mathbb N$ is a set. $0 \in \mathbb N$, $S : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $, $+, \times: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. How does it prove infinity?

Comment: It is fairly standard to verify that the existence of an infinite set implies the existence of an inductive one (essentially, from replacement, once you have a Dedekind infinite set you can show that $\omega $ is a set). It is provable in your theory that the set you call $\mathbb N $ is infinite. In your case, $\mathbb N $ is Dedekind infinite, but even a Dedekind finite infinite set suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theory proves Infinity and so in particular proves all consequences of ZFC (including Con(PA)).  This is pretty much immediate: the set $\mathbb{N}$ for your model must be infinite (for instance, because there is a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ which is injective but not surjective; this follows from finitely many axioms of PA).

Alternatively and more directly, let $s:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the successor map, and let $A$ be the set of all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which are in every set which contains $0$ and is closed under $s$.  Then you can prove as usual that $A$ satisfies the second-order Peano axioms (this is pretty much immediate from its definition), and so gives a model of PA.